# c++ virtual destructor in decorator pattern

Tags: c++, virtual, decorator, destructor

I recently encountered the decorator pattern in my school assignment and would like to ask the details of implementing destructors in decorator class.

Consider the following Decorator class

```
class Decorator:public Base{
    protected: 
        Base &base;
        Decorator(Base &b):base(b){}
        virtual ~Decorator(){delete &(this->base)}
        //other methods here
};
```

in my derived class for `Decorator`

```
class Derived:public Decorator{
    public:
        Derived(Base& b):Decorator(b){};
        ~Derived(){delete &(this->base)}; //want a custom destructor here       
};
```

But the following code would not work, consider

```
Base* b1 = new Base;
b1 = new Derived(*b1);
//do stuff with b1
delete b1; //segmentation fault
```

The question is:

1. why did it not work? What did I do wrong in implementing the destructor?
2. I changed by code by deleting the `virtual` keyword in `~Decorator()` and commenting out the `~Derived()` but this is not a good fix considering I want my custom destructor in `Derived` class
3. Is there a better way to implement the decorator pattern? How?

EDIT:

I don't have a real-life use case for this except that provided in our assignment. 
We are asked to implement a textprocessor that would have the following functions (Decorators):

DropFirst n Drop the first n characters of each word. If n is greater than the length of some word, the entire word is dropped (though the following word is not affected).
Files to create: dropfirst.h and dropfirst.cc

• DoubleWords Double up all words in the string. Files to create: doublewords.h and droublewords.cc

• AllCaps All letters in the string are presented in uppercase. Other characters remain unchanged. Files to create: allcaps.h and allcaps.cc

• Count c The first occurrence of the character c in the string is replaced with 1. The second is replaced with 2, ... the tenth is replaced with 10, and so on. Files to create: count.h and count.cc

Suppose the textprocessor is given "hello world" and decorated by `doublewords dropfirst 2 count l`

It would output

```
12o
34o
r5d
r6d
sample.txt allcaps
HELLO
WORLD
```

Comment: you should definetly look at [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are deleting Base &base twice: first, the destructor for Derived deletes this->base, then the destructor for Decorator (parent) deletes this->base again. The solution is that Decorator should be the only one that deletes this->base.

Comment: You mean the `Decorator` class? In the base class there was no custom destructor. Also, I am calling `virtual ~Decorator` which means that my `~Derived()` should override the destructor in `Decorator`

Comment: @Han_Chen, right I mean Decorator. It doesn't override it, first the destructor for Derived is called and then the destructor for Decorator.

Comment: That should explain it, I thought for some reason a virtual method will be overridden by derived class, but apparently not, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Destructor and constructor should always go in marriage. Always (in 99.99999%) cases you can only `delete` something in destructor if you `new`ed in constructor. Since you did not your code is buggy. Adopt this simple logical rule, and your life will become much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but that is most certainly not the way to do polymorphism. Try this code out, pay special attention to the order things are carried out.

```
class base
{

    int* heapint;
public:

    base()
    {
        cout<<"creating base object, including a heap allocated int"<<endl;
        heapint = new int(25);
    }


    virtual ~base()
    {
        cout<<"Now destroying base object, including the heapint"<<endl;
        delete heapint;
    }

    virtual int getHeapint()
    {
        return *heapint;
    }

    virtual void overRideTest()
    {
        cout<<"This function is to be overrided in the subtype"<<endl;
    }


};

class subtype : public base
{
public:
    subtype()
    {
        cout<<"creating subtype"<<endl;
    }

    ~subtype()
    {
        cout<<"destroying subtype"<<endl;
    }

    void overRideTest() override
    {
        cout<<"This function was invoced, despite the ptr being of type base*"<<endl;
    }

};


int main()
{

    base* ptr = new subtype();
    cout<<"getting value of heapint: "<<ptr->getHeapint()<<endl;//notice how I need to create a virtual get function in base.
    ptr->overRideTest();
    delete ptr;
}
```

I suspect you've made the same missunderstanding I made when trying to figure polymorphism out: When you instantiate the subtype, you are actually creating a complex datastructure consisting of two objects(three if you count the vtable), one base, and one subtype. Simply put, the two objects are still distinct, despite what you may otherwise think.

Furthermore, notice I never attempt to handle the memory of the the basetype outside of the basetype. You shouldn't need to have a pointer back to the basetype in your subtypes, that means you've done something wierd, and probably wrong. The object that allocates on the heap(ie using new), should also be the one deallocating said object.

Edit: I forgot to add: Notice how the basetype is the first to be created, but last to be destroyed. Virtual objects are destroyed in the opposite order in which they were created.